# How to import some file into entry file for webpack?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, swagger-ui

I use the [Node.js API](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/) for the `webpack.config.ts`:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';

export const config: Configuration = {
  // ...
  context: resolve(__dirname),
  entry: {
    swaggerUi: './index.ts'
  },
  // ...
};
```

The problem occurs when I try to import any file into the entry file - `index.ts`:

```
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui';
import 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css';
import { urlConfig } from './swagger.config';

const ui = SwaggerUI({
  url: urlConfig.url,
  dom_id: '#swagger',
});

ui.initOAuth({
  appName: 'Swagger UI Webpack Demo',
  clientId: 'implicit'
});
```

This throw an error:

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './swagger.config' in '/srv/git/ditsmod/ditsmod/packages/openapi/src/swagger-ui'"

But the `swagger.config.ts` file actually exists in the same directory with `index.ts`.

What am I doing wrong and how to import some file into entry file for webpack?

Comment: Is the file called `swagger.config` or `swagger.config.ts`?

Comment: @blaumeise20, `swagger.config.ts`

Comment: What do you have in your webpack config `resolve` and do you use `ts-loader`?

Comment: @blaumeise20, after your comment I added `ts-loader`, but unfortunately it did not fix the issue.

Comment: And what is the `resolve` option in the config?

Comment: @blaumeise20, I do not use the `resolve` configuration at all. How do you advise to use it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the `resolve` webpack option. You need to specify it so that webpack knows that you want to resolve `.ts` files:

```json
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".tsx"], // remove .tsx if you don't need the jsx syntax
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this solved the described issue, but now there is a new issue - imports local file using compilerOptions.path (e.g `import { some } from '@ditsmod/core'`)

Comment: Can you open another question?

Comment: Oh! After removing `ts-loader` the problem disappeared. That is, the only thing I had to do was what you described in this answer.